# Export data into CSV file in ADLS gen 2

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to export multiple path file details into csv file. But it is only taking last path and storing details into csv file. FYI,

$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "cordus6abfsuat001" -UseConnectedAccount
$path="path1",
"path2",
"path3",
"path4",
"path5"
foreach($element in $path){
$temp = Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem -Context $Context -FileSystem "root" -Path $element | export-csv "filename.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}

I am expecting that all the above mentioned path file details will come to csv file. but it is taking last path details only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve your requirement after adding -Append to the existing `export-csv` command. Below is the complete script that worked for me.

```
$path="dir1/", "dir2/", "dir3/", "dir4/", "dir5/" 
foreach($element in $path)
{ 
    Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem -Context $context -FileSystem "root" -Path $element | export-csv "<filename>.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]